# Function to sum of a range of cells meeting a condition while skipping hidden rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there an Excel function to calculate the sum of a range of cells containing hidden rows (filtered by the user using an auto filter) and that meet a certain condition?

For example, consider the following sheet:

```
  |  A          | B      |
1 | numbers     | country|
2 | 1           | X      |
3 | 2           | X      | 
4 | 3           | Y      |
5 | 4           | X      |
```

Applying an auto filter only showing country X, this results in the following, where row 4 gets hidden:

```
  |  A          | B      |
1 | numbers     | country|
2 | 1           | X      |
3 | 2           | X      | 
5 | 4           | X      |
```

I would like to calculate the sum of the numbers in column A greater than 1 while taking the autofilter by the user into account.

I've tried the following solution by combining SUBTOTAL with an array filter:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9;(A2:A5>=2)*(A2:A5))
```

This probably does not work due the mismatch of argument types. I do not know how I can convert an array into a reference.

Comment: This example might indeed seem a bit abstract, but the additional filter of skipping the `1` does not have to be specified by the user, but has to be skipped for computational reasons. Hence I require a mechanism to handle both a user-defined filter (using autofilter) and my own filter. I could create another column solely containing the numbers I'd like to sum, but creating additional columns is something I wish to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Based on mehow his answer I created this function, which evaluates an condition before calculating the sum.

```
Function SumVisibleWithCondition(MyRange As Range, Condition As String) As Integer
    Dim sum As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In MyRange
        If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If Evaluate("" & c.Value & Condition) Then
                sum = sum + c.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    SumVisibleWithCondition = sum
  End Function
```

Comment: Although correct, this snippit doesn't cover all datatypes and cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the method suggested [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/05/11/arrays-with-offset/)

For your example formula would be

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9;OFFSET(A2;ROW(A2:A5)-ROW(A2);0))*(A2:A5>=2))`